# How do I make this style an external CSS/SCSS file?

Tags: html, css

I have a peculiar code here for a Javascript dropdown menu, but I think it uses some kind of dynamic CSS.

After much tinkering I got the darn thing working. The thing is, I need the CSS to be a seperate file to import into the HTML document. This is where things get tricky. I have no idea what kind of code this is as I've never worked with it before. Does anyone have any idea how I can link this CSS to my HTML document externally?

```html
<style class="cp-pen-styles">@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900");
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico);
body {
  font-family: "Lato", Helvetica, Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-border-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-border-sizing: border-box;
  border-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 350px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
.container > ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

.title {
  font-family: 'Pacifico';
  font-weight: norma;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.4;
  color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown [data-toggle="dropdown"] {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  background: #E6E6E6;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #EDEDED inset, 0 -1px 0 #C0C0C0 inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #EDEDED inset, 0 -1px 0 #C0C0C0 inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #EDEDED inset, 0 -1px 0 #C0C0C0 inset;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 10px;
}
.dropdown [data-toggle="dropdown"]:hover {
  background: #C0C0C0;
}
.dropdown .icon-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  color: #fff;
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
}
.dropdown .icon-arrow.open {
  -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.6s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
}
.dropdown .icon-arrow.close {
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.6s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
}
.dropdown .icon-arrow:before {
  content: '\25BC';
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li {
  padding: 0;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li a {
  display: block;
  color: #6e6e6e;
  background: #EEE;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white inset, 0 -1px 0 #d4d4d4 inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white inset, 0 -1px 0 #d4d4d4 inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white inset, 0 -1px 0 #d4d4d4 inset;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
  background: #f6f6f6;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu li ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #6e6e6e;
  background: #EEE;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white inset, 0 -1px 0 #d4d4d4 inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white inset, 0 -1px 0 #d4d4d4 inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white inset, 0 -1px 0 #d4d4d4 inset;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu li ul li a:hover {
  background: #f6f6f6;
}

.dropdown .show, .dropdown .hide {
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
}
.dropdown .show {
  display: block;
  max-height: 9999px;
  -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
  animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
}
.dropdown .hide {
  max-height: 0;
  -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
  -webkit-animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
  transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
}

@keyframes showAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes showAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes showAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}
@keyframes hideAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes hideAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes hideAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}
</style>
```

What do I need to keep in the HTML document to link it to the CSS document, and what do I need to save in the CSS document? You can't put the imports in a CSS document.

I already tried to save everything strating from `body (..};`til `</script>` and then making the code in the HTML:

```html
<style class="cp-pen-styles" src="dropstyle.">@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900");
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico);
</style>
```

But that did not work for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why externally? Why not add it to the top of the html page? After any other css calls if you want it to override

Comment: Sorry if this is a really easy problem and I'm just dumb. I'm only a student trying to learn programming. I'm in way over my head and need some help because I'm stuck.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney my supervisor says so. That's really the only reason. If it were up to me I'd keep it inside of the HTML document because it simply works, but I'm not allowed to.

Comment: Then save it as an external file and simply include it at the top of your html document `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/the/file.css"/>`

Comment: What do I do with the imports? Where do I leave those?

Comment: Your tiip worked for me, but the fonts were not imported. If you can fix that problem for me and post it as an answer I'll give you the correct answer and close the question. Thank you! :)

Comment: Put the link to the google fonts in the head section like this `<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your fonts imports can stay in you css file. However, in the CSS file you should NOT have the `<style class="cp-pen-styles">` and `</style>` tags. Put everything in between them in the CSS file and then like the others mentioned, add the line below to the header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/the/file.css"/>
```

So your CSS file will look like this:

```
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900");
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico);
body {
  font-family: "Lato", Helvetica, Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-border-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-border-sizing: border-box;
  border-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 350px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
.container > ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

.title {
  font-family: 'Pacifico';
  font-weight: norma;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.4;
  color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown [data-toggle="dropdown"] {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  background: #E6E6E6;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #EDEDED inset, 0 -1px 0 #C0C0C0 inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #EDEDED inset, 0 -1px 0 #C0C0C0 inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #EDEDED inset, 0 -1px 0 #C0C0C0 inset;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 10px;
}
.dropdown [data-toggle="dropdown"]:hover {
  background: #C0C0C0;
}
.dropdown .icon-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  color: #fff;
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
}
.dropdown .icon-arrow.open {
  -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.6s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
}
.dropdown .icon-arrow.close {
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.6s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
}
.dropdown .icon-arrow:before {
  content: '\25BC';
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li {
  padding: 0;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li a {
  display: block;
  color: #6e6e6e;
  background: #EEE;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white inset, 0 -1px 0 #d4d4d4 inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white inset, 0 -1px 0 #d4d4d4 inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white inset, 0 -1px 0 #d4d4d4 inset;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
  background: #f6f6f6;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu li ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #6e6e6e;
  background: #EEE;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white inset, 0 -1px 0 #d4d4d4 inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white inset, 0 -1px 0 #d4d4d4 inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white inset, 0 -1px 0 #d4d4d4 inset;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu li ul li a:hover {
  background: #f6f6f6;
}

.dropdown .show, .dropdown .hide {
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
}
.dropdown .show {
  display: block;
  max-height: 9999px;
  -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
  animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
}
.dropdown .hide {
  max-height: 0;
  -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
  -webkit-animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
  transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
}

@keyframes showAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes showAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes showAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}
@keyframes hideAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes hideAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes hideAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking Darren's comment and adding it here, put the link to your style sheet inside the head section like this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/the/file.css"/>`

My part: To link your fonts add this to your head section:

`<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

Just so wee can close this question :)

Answer (score 1):

To link the CSS code you have posted here to a HTML document you need to do a few things.

1: Create a file with the name main.css (make sure you put it inside the same folder as the HTML file you want to link to).

2: Paste the CSS code into the main.css document you have just created

3: Go to the top of the HTML document you wish to link it to and do the following inside the head of the HTML doc.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
```